# Google Maps Geocode unexpected property location

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to set up geocoding for my vue.js app. I'm not using any third party library, only google maps installed via npm.

When calling the geocode method, it throws an error saying, that the property location is unexpected. I've tried "location", "latlng", the coordinates itself and so on. Longitude and latitude come from the `navigator.geolocation` object.

Here is a part of my setup-script:

```
Vue.component('catalog', require('./components/Catalog'));
Vue.component('address-autocomplete', require('./components/AddressAutoComplete'));
window.googleMapsClient = require('@google/maps').createClient({
    key: "MY_API_KEY"
});
```

And my Vue-component:

```
getLocationFromGeoData() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            this.setLocation,
            this.showError
        );
    } else {
        showLocationError("Geolocation wird nicht unterstützt!");
    }
},
setLocation(position) {
    var self = this;

    this.location.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    this.location.longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    var latLng = {
        lat: parseFloat(this.location.latitude),
        lng: parseFloat(this.location.longitude)
    };

    googleMapsClient.geocode({'location': latLng}).asPromise()
        .then((response) => {
            self.location.address = results[1].formatted_address;
        }).catch((err) => {
            showLocationError(err);
        });
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note that you try to resolve a coordinate to the address. This process typically is called **reverse geocoding**. That means you must use a `.reverseGeocode(query, callback)` method instead of `.geocode(query, callback)` method.

Your code should be changed to something similar to

```
var latLng = {
    lat: parseFloat(this.location.latitude),
    lng: parseFloat(this.location.longitude)
};

googleMapsClient.reverseGeocode({'latlng': latLng}).asPromise()
    .then((response) => {
        self.location.address = results[1].formatted_address;
    }).catch((err) => {
        showLocationError(err);
    });
```

For more details have a look at the documentation of Maps Web Services client library for Node.js at

https://googlemaps.github.io/google-maps-services-js/docs/GoogleMapsClient.html

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

`geocode` is method of class `google.maps.Geocoder` - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding.

```
const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status) { // code
```

Comment: As you can see [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google/maps) your answer would be the solution if I wanted to include google maps via script-tag. But I'am using the npm package..